# Angular Firestore query a collection using two where conditions with equal

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm doing a web application using Angular 8 and [Angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire). I'm trying to query a collection using two `where` with `==`, but, it's not working.

I was following the official guide of [querying-collection](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) from Angularfire.

Using this code there is no results at all:

```
getChats(): Observable<IChatRoom[]> {
    return this.afs.collection<IChatRoom>('chats', ref => {
      let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
      query = query.where('state', '==', 'open');
      query = query.where('state', '==', 'transferred');
      return query;
    }).valueChanges();
  }
```

It works only with one `where`, like this:

```
getChats(): Observable<IChatRoom[]> {
    return this.afs.collection<IChatRoom>('chats', ref => {
      let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
      query = query.where('state', '==', 'open');
      return query;
    }).valueChanges();
  }
```

I have also tried:

```
getChats(): Observable<IChatRoom[]> {
    return this.afs.collection<IChatRoom>('chats', ref =>
      ref
        .where('state', '==', 'open')
        .where('state', '==', 'transferred')
    ).valueChanges();
  }
```

My goal is to get all documents in a collection that have the `state` field **equal** to `open` or `transferred`.

Comment: Multiple where clauses are always logically AND'd together.  You can't use them to logically OR their conditions.  Use an "IN" query to check for multiple values in a single field.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the clarification, now it's working. I didn't know about the existence of the `in`, it should be mentioned in the querying-collection from Angularfire.

Comment: Great point. Feel like filing a bug on the [AngularFire2 repo](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md) (and maybe a PR too of how you'd like to see it fixed)?